# Cannot Persist a nested dictionary in swift

Tags: swift

This line works:

```
userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("orch_array")?[orchId]?[appleId]
```

However, when I try to set this....it fails

```
userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("orch_array")?[orchId]?[appleId] = []
```

With ERROR:

> Could not find member 'subscript'

Comment: First one is an empty op but the second you are trying to run a subscript assignment op on AnyObject , the output of orchId's key

Answer (score 0):

```
let dict:[NSObject:AnyObject] = ["orchId":["appleId":["item1","item2"]]]

NSUserDefaults().setObject(dict, forKey: "orch_array")

if var loadedObj = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("orch_array") as? [String:[String:[String]]] {
    print(loadedObj["orchId"]!["appleId"]!)  // "[item1, item2]"
    loadedObj["orchId"]?["appleId"] = []
    NSUserDefaults().setObject(loadedObj, forKey: "orch_array")
}


if let loadedAgain = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("orch_array") as? [String:[String:[String]]] {
    print(loadedAgain["orchId"]!["appleId"]!)   // []
}
```